AHKV1: How to get the first 'keyWait' to stop holding up the programme?
I have a situation where while I hold down the space key, if a key is pressed, carry out an additional action and then, upon releasing space key, do the default action.
I have come up with the following code:
Space::
    tooltip, "space" is down
    KeyWait, a, d
        tooltip, "a" was pressed, carrying out "additional action"
    KeyWait, space
        tooltip, "space" is up, carrying out "default action"
    return

It works as I expect it to if while space is down, I tap a key, then release space key, both tooltips fire. However, if while space is down, I did not tap the a key, the script will be stuck because the first keywait is halting the script and still waiting for its key to be tapped.
Upon releasing space, I essentially need the first keywait to be disregarded and the script execution to be carried on.
With standard AHK, I can essentially solve the above problem as follows, but I am using a library called MouseGestureL and I cannot use hotkey assignments within it (::), hence what I am trying to do:
~Space::
    tooltip, "space" is down
    KeyWait, space
    tooltip, "space" is up
    return
Space & a::
        tooltip, "a" was pressed
    return

I am on the latest AutoHotkey V1, as this library has not been ported to V2.
I have tried many things to solve this issue, am just going around in circles at this point, would appreciate any help.

You say "I am using a library called MouseGestureL and I cannot use hotkey assignments within it (::)". Why not? For me is no problem. I can add as many hotkeys as I need in the script MouseGestureL.ahk and they are working.
